# Necessary and sufficient condition to be completely multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, multiplicative-function, dirichlet-convolution

I want to prove that $f*f=f \tau$ iff $f$ is completely multiplicative. The "if" part was relatively easy, using $f(g*h)=(fg)*(fh)$ and plug $g=h=1$ for all $n$.

Juxtaposition is ordinary, pointwise product and $*$ is dirichlet convolution.

My attempt: Using well-ordering property, let $a,b$ be a pair of integers with smallest product such that $f(ab) \neq f(a)f(b)$, and arriving to contradiction. But this does not seem to work.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $f(1)\ne 0,1$ then $f\ast f(1)= f(1)^2\ne f(1)=f(1)\tau(1)$.
- If $f(1)= 0$ then take the least $n$ such that $f(n)\ne 0$, you'll have $f\ast f(n)=0\ne  f(n)\tau(n)$.
- So assume that $f(1)=1$.

Take the least $n$ such that $f(n)\ne \prod_{p^k\| n} f(p)^k$.

For all $m$ let $g(m)=\prod_{p^k\| m} f(p)^k$.

then $$f\ast f(n)-f(n)\tau(n) = g\ast g(n) + f(n)-g(n)-f(n)\tau(n)$$ $$= 
g(n)\tau(n)+f(n)-g(n)-f(n)\tau(n)= (g(n)-f(n))(\tau(n)-1)\ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is very clear and understandable.

Comment: Actually, I made my own solution.
We want to show that $f(p^k)=f(p)^k$. $k=1$ case is clear. So, by strong induction, let $f(p^i)=f(p)^i$ for all $i$ less than $k$. then, $f(p^k) \tau(p^k) = (k+1) f(p^k) = f(1)f(p^k)+f(p)f(p^{k-1})+\cdots +f(p)f(1) = 2f(p^k) + (k-1)f(p)^k$ 

and done.

Is this correct?

Comment: you need to show that f is multiplivcative as well

Comment: Oh, that was also included in the problem. I forgot to mention it in the question. Except that point, is the solution(by induction) correct? I am new to number theory so I and not sure about everything :(